# How to apply condition for print values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

how to apply condition for print values ​​of an array

hello staff S.O.F
I need help from you again,

this function shuffle numbers,

`

```
function gen_num()
{
$caracteres = "012345678910111213141516171819";
$mistura = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres),0,15);
print $mistura;
```

`

I needed a condition to print or not the numbers at the posts, and the @leglesslizard User helped me. It works perfectly, the big problem down was that each new access to posts, or refresh the kapok, a new number / value was generated, and this could not happen, I needed to write permanently on those values ​​in the posts and below the solution but can not apply in arrays!

`

```
function gen_num()
{
global $post;
$mistura = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_meta', true );

if ( '' == $mistura ) {
$caracteres = "012345678910111213141516171819";
$mistura = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres),0,10);
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_meta', $mistura );
}

print $mistura;
}
```

`

I am now trying to make arrays and I can not!

`

```
function shuflenames()
{
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
```

`

my failed attempt to apply condition with arrays:

`

```
function shuflenames()
{
global $post;
$mixnames = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_meta', true );
if ( '' == $mixnames) {
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_meta', $mixnames );
}
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
}
```

`

but the words change as the condition does not exist. every new access words are changed, they are not actually written in the posts

Comment: Why do you update the post meta with it existing value? And what is not working exactly? It's pretty unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Vard :) .. Printed values ​​were not written permanently in the pages, it change every new access on pages. want a shuffle to all be different, but in the first run he writes permanently, as in the first case not writing, so I made that change with the condition to not write if already there is a value in place, he decided, but I do not make your arrays. I want someone to tell me how to do this with arrays.
 Thanks for reply.

Comment: note that showed a first case that could solve, the values ​​in numeric shuffle I managed to get them to be written once, with the solution below it, I want to do that in the second case, a function with arrays, I do not do the function write truly permanent in the posts before the first case, each access generated a new number the pages, never saw the same number now managed to solve with the solution below, each page has a unique number, and ever written, not change more each refresh on the page, not to do with managing arrays. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution the user @bcworkz: in wordpress dot org responded and helped me:

```
function gen_num()
{
  global $post;
  $mixnames = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fieldnames', true );

  if ( '' == $mixnames ) {
    $input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
    $mixnames = $input[$rand_keys[1]];
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fieldnames', $mixnames );
  }
  // DISPLAYS THE OUTCOME
  print $mixnames;
}
```